# My app is not running but there are no errors

Tags: android

My app was running perfect until i added a new graphic background in a button.From this time i m getting a message when i m trying to rum my app `"You project contains error(S), please fix them before running your application"`. I have tried to clean my app, refresh it but nothing changes.Also,in the package explorer there is no red sign nowhere in that project....I import the same project in my Macbook and its running with no problem.So,where is the problem in that pc eclipse?Thanks

Comment: i have tried also to restart eclipse,then to restart my pc for several times but still the same problem!May i have to re install eclipse?

Comment: i now realized that i cant run any project from eclipse...my old apps are not running too!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I recently had this issue. The issue was caused because my debug certificate had expired. So what I did was go to the .android location in windows and delete the file debug.keystore.
After deleting, I cleaned and build my project, this fixed the issues. In my machine this was the location of the keystore, you might need to search

```
E:\Users\blessan\.android
```

Comment: Well good that it helped. I had this problem yesterday. And took me the whole day to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

reference entry of any updated file is still not updated , so R contains error . i know in gen folder R is not red crossed .
 work around is open recently changed res files (layout/values ) make little changes (so that new reference can be saved ) and save it . now clean and build .

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered same problem. When I tried to run my project, the error message is displayed **"You project contains error(S), please fix them before running your application"**. But when I build the project, there was no error and same error again on running my app.

So, I went to **Build Path -> Configure Build Path -> Java Build Path**, and there was an extra entity other than Android 3.1(in my case). So I removed that and application runs good.